# Compare two sums using prime number theorem

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Let $$A(x)=x\sum_{p \leq x} 1, B(x)=\frac{3}{5}\sum_{x<p\leq 2x}p$$ Using prime number theorem, we have $A(x)\sim\frac{x^2}{\log{x}}$, but how to obtain an estimation for $B(x)$?

Comment: Where does $B(x)$ comes from? The $\frac 35$ is really mesmerizing.

Comment: I am also puzzled about that $\frac{3}{5}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum of the primes up to $x$ is, asymptotically, $(1/2)x^2/\log x$. So asymptotically, $$B(x)=(3/5)((1/2)(2x)^2/\log(2x)-(1/2)x^2/\log x))$$ Looks like about $(9/10)x^2/\log x$.

Comment: Where do you get that asymptotic formula for the sum of primes up to x? Can I find this result in Apostol?

Comment: You can get ot out of http://oeis.org/A007504 but there are probably more direct ways. Maybe a better place is http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeSums.html

Comment: @Rob, just try to apply summation by part and use prime number theorem, you can get the asymptote directly.